# This questions can not be closed, but plz do not comment any more. thankyou! --- the frog

Tags: java, arrays

---

> What's wrong with my code? It will not print what I think my code is
> doing. This is question -2022 J3 Harp Tuning- from Canadian Computing
> Contest

---

**Sample Input 1**

AFB+8HC-4

**Output for Sample Input 1**

AFB tighten 8

HC loosen 4

**Explanation of Sample Output 1**

The input contains two tuning instructions:
AFB+8 and HC-4

**Sample Input 2**

AFB+8SC-4H-2GDPE+9

**Output for Sample Input 2**

AFB tighten 8

SC loosen 4

H loosen 2

GDPE tighten 9

**Explanation of Sample Output 2**

The input contains four tuning instructions:
AFB+8, SC-4, H-2, and GDPE+9

*I've tried to use Array and String, non worked.
**FYI** I am NOT allowed to use complicated stuff in my code as my teacher said (yes I will get marks off if I do)*

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] input = {in.nextLine()};
        String num = "1234567890";
        for (int i = 0 ;i < input.length;i++)
        {
            if (num.contains(String.valueOf(input.length)))
            {
                input[i]=input[i]+"\n";
                //continue;
            }//end of if
            if (input[i]=="+")
            {
                input[i]=" tighten ";
            }//end of if
            if (input[i]=="-")
            {
                input[i]=" loosen ";
            }//end of if
        }// end of for
        printArry(input);
   }// end of main

    public static void printArry(String[]a)
    {
           for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) 
           {
              System.out.print(a[j]);
           }// end of for
    }// end of printArry
}//end of class
```

Comment: `{in.nextLine()}` may be array literal syntax the compiler accepts, but how would you describe what it (and other lines) do in a natural language such as English?

Comment: You are trying to use us as human debuggers while the job can be done much more efficiently with an actual debugger. Search for "How to use <my-IDE> debugger" and step through your code with your IDE. Then you'll have your answer in no time.

Comment: `String.valueOf(input.length)` will return the same number (as String) with every iteration. And that number is „1“, because input is an array with one element, so the length is 1.

Answer (score 2):

The pattern seems to be nondigits - followed by plus or minus - then digits. I would literally use a `Pattern` to represent that regular expression. Then loop over the matches to the pattern. That might look something like

```
String[] inputs = { "AFB+8HC-4", "AFB+8SC-4H-2GDPE+9" };
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\D+)([+-])(\\d+)");
for (String s : inputs) {
    System.out.printf("For %s%n", s);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.printf("%s %s %s%n",
                m.group(1),
                m.group(2).equals("+") ? "tighten" : "loosen",
                m.group(3));
    }
}
```

Outputs (as requested)

```
For AFB+8HC-4
AFB tighten 8
HC loosen 4
For AFB+8SC-4H-2GDPE+9
AFB tighten 8
SC loosen 4
H loosen 2
GDPE tighten 9
```

Comment: Your solution is working, but it does not address the lack of Java basics shown by the question's author.

Comment: Thank you for ur answer. However, we are not allowed to use Pattern nor Matcher